# How To Substring and Add a Range

Tags: mysql, substring

I have an URL that needs to be shortened. I have 2 formats of the URL, first one is `/item/10/0100-`, it stops at first `-`, the second one is `/item/12/0100-CAK`, it needs 3 more characters after the `-`.

Below is the example,

```
/item/10/0100-NAU1X010-10-A032 need to be /item/10/0100- 
/item/2/0888-ADBACS11101-2-A048 need to be /item/2/0888-
/item/12/0100-CAK101827812018101-12-A034 need to be /item/12/0100-CAK 
/item/3/0110-MSS0016-T03-3-A034 need to be /item/3/0110-MSS
```

I already try this query

```
CASE
 WHEN Page LIKE "/item/10%" OR Page LIKE "/item/2/%" THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(Page, LOCATE('/', Page)+1), '-', 1), "-")
 WHEN Page LIKE "/item/12%" OR Page LIKE "/item/3/%" THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(Page, LOCATE('/', Page)+1), '-', 1) + 4
ELSE Page
END
```

But it doesn't give me the right result. It seems simple but I really can't get over it. Please help me with this problem, thank you.

Comment: @Akina what about the 2nd format? The 3 characters are not only `CAK`

Comment: @Akina for the first format, `/item/10/0100-NAU1X010-10-A032` need to be `/item/10/0100-` and `/item/2/0888-ADBACS11101-2-A048` need to be `/item/2/0888-`. For the second format `/item/12/0100-CAK101827812018101-12-A034` need to be `/item/12/0100-CAK` and `/item/3/0110-MSS0016-T03-3-A034` need to be `/item/3/0110-MSS`

Comment: The 2 formats are actually 1 format only. So how can you tell which format applies to each URL?

Comment: @forpas it divided by the number after `/item/`. Please take a look at my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string functions in the CASE expression like this:

```
SELECT 
  page,
  CASE
    WHEN Page LIKE '/item/10%' OR Page LIKE '/item/2/%' THEN 
      CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Page, '-', 1), '-')
    WHEN Page LIKE '/item/12%' OR Page LIKE '/item/3/%' THEN 
      CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Page, '-', 1), SUBSTR(Page, LOCATE('-', Page), 4))
    ELSE Page
  END short_Page
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3338162c7eaedd4ac8cfe15600793930).
Results:

```
> page                                     | short_Page       
> :--------------------------------------- | :----------------
> /item/10/0100-NAU1X010-10-A032           | /item/10/0100-   
> /item/2/0888-ADBACS11101-2-A048          | /item/2/0888-    
> /item/12/0100-CAK101827812018101-12-A034 | /item/12/0100-CAK
> /item/3/0110-MSS0016-T03-3-A034          | /item/3/0110-MSS
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Path,
       SUBSTRING(Path FROM 1 FOR LOCATE('-', Path) + 3 * (@format = 2)) AS shortened
FROM test;
```

---

> The format is differentiated by the number after /item/

```
SELECT Path,
       SUBSTRING(Path FROM 1 FOR LOCATE('-', Path) + 3 * (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Path, '/', 3), '/', -1) IN (12, 3))) AS shortened,
       (SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Path, '/', 3), '/', -1) IN (12, 3)) + 1 used_format
FROM test;
```

Adjust the values list for `format 2`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af955c2bf4a49713d1ddc551fd8be741)

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding in my question. When the URL starts with `/item/10/` it must be the first format and when it starts with `/item/12/` then it must be the second format. Maybe I will edit my question.

Comment: @HilmanDhannysworo *When the URL starts with /item/10/ it must be the first format and when it starts with /item/12/ then it must be the second format.* Unclear. Why `/item/2/` means format1 and `/item/3/` means format2 - you say nothing about these values...

Comment: sorry about my unclear explanation. The format is differentiated by the number after `/item/`. Please take a look at my edited question.

Comment: can you explain a little bit to me about your query? I mean, this is clearly some out of my league kind of query :')

Comment: Double SUBSTRING_INDEX extracts *the number after /item/* which then tested for matching to format 2 list. If it is in list the compare gives TRUE which is 1 else it gives FALSE which is 0. Then this result is used in SUBSTRING for to increase extracted substring length by 3 if format 2 needed.